# How to find which part of my system still references a certain device

Tags: grub2, 20.04, uefi

Consider the following excerpt from a recent `apt-get dist-upgrade` run:

```
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic (5.4.0-59.65) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-59-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-59-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
  /dev/sdg: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdg: open failed: No medium found
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme1n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

You will notice the two lines stating `/dev/sdg: open failed: No medium found`.

That drive is one that I have attached to the system on occasion, but not usually. It's an SSD which I keep fully bootable for use as an alternative system.

What's strange is that this device keeps popping up during package upgrades and I don't know where that information is retrieved from in absence of the device.

A casual:

```
grep -aRi '/dev/sdg' /boot /etc
```

yielded nothing at all. Likewise looking at `efibootmgr -v` output I can see that the respective EFI entry for the disk that is referred to as `/dev/sdg` in the above message merely references the drive by number and UUID of the partition. So I am puzzled where it takes the `/dev/sdg` from.

**Question:** So where is that information stored?

**Edit:** Forgot: Ubuntu 20.04 with latest patches applied.

---

Findings so far:

- The reference to `/dev/sdg` gets produced by the `os-prober` script

  - The step which calls `lvs` is the cause ...
    The exact invocation is `lvs --noheadings --separator : -o vg_name,lv_name`
- Other LVM-related commands give the same output

  - Using `--verbose` and/or `--debug` with the LVM tools doesn't change anything, it provides no more insights
- There were a few files in `/etc/lvm/archive`, but they referred to removed logical volumes ... I removed them (but backup is available by way of `etckeeper`, if needed)
- The output happens to stderr

Comment: Look at `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg` and `/etc/fstab` with `less`. Is it  currently mounted? `mount | grep sdg`.

Comment: @waltinator no, the disk isn't mounted. Could you explain how looking at those files underneath `/etc` could yield anything different than the recursive case-insensitive `grep` invocation with the inclusion of all files being treated as text?

Comment: Read the files, see how they work, figure out where they get their `sdg` information from, ... Read `man update-initramfs`

Comment: @waltinator I'm not sure how that's supposed to help. `/etc/default/grub` (and `grub.d`) were the first places I looked in. There is _no_ mention of `/dev/sdg` _anywhere_ in `/etc` or `/boot` nor in the list `efibootmgr -v` spits out (as I wrote). That drive is - quite intentionally - not mentioned in `/etc/fstab`, it's not mounted either. All relevant hook scripts for `update-initramfs` should be in `/etc`, but there are no hooks or scripts on my system. It had been a while since I read `man update-initramfs`, so I did it again. But I don't even understand what connection there could be?!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was basically chasing a ghost problem. TL;DR: the card-reader hardware was causing the issue.

While at some point I did have a device that would be available as `sdg` and therefore it was reasonable to assume that there is some remnant of that in some configuration, the cause turned out to be something else.

In addition to the observations detailed in the question, `lsblk`, `blkid` and similar tools did not show `sdg` at all. The LVM-related tools only gave the above mentioned error output.

As it turns out, my machine *did* have a `/dev/sdg` nevertheless, created by the kernel. And that's when I realized that there must be *something* which causes the kernel to create that device node. Alas `inxi -F` also didn't show anything. However, `lshw` was able to shed some light on the mystery. And this is what the respective output looked (excerpt):

```
 *-scsi:6
      physical id: 2d
      logical name: scsi8
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         product: SD/MMC CRW
         vendor: Generic-
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdg
         version: 1.00
         serial: 2012062914345300
         capabilities: removable
         configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/sdg
```

It was the card-reader hardware all along. And the error was shown because there was no card in it at the time `os-prober` called `lvs` ...

My main lesson from this is not to trust tools like `lsblk` and `blkid` or even `inxi` and always look for the actual device node or use other tools to query information.